# How can I modify a reference to a field within the same struct using Rc and RefCell?

Tags: rust, refcell

I have a struct with a field that references the current element on an array in the same struct using `Rc`. I can now have a reference to any element from then `nums` field:

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

struct ArrayTest {
    nums: [u32; 8],
    cur_num: Rc<RefCell<Option<u32>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut slice = ArrayTest {
        nums: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        cur_num: Rc::new(RefCell::new(None)),
    };

    slice.cur_num = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Some(1)));
    let ref mut t = slice.nums[3];
    slice.cur_num = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Some(*t)));

    println!("{:?}", slice.cur_num);
    if let Some(ref mut t) = *slice.cur_num.borrow_mut() {
        *t += 1;
    };
    println!("{:?}", slice.cur_num);
    println!("{:?}", slice.nums);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d46b486ff43b7c680f3cd4f516d05cd)

The problem comes when I try to modify `cur_num`, because I want it to reflect its value on the `nums` array. Whenever I try to do so by dereferencing it, it seems like it only changes `cur_num`.

```
RefCell { value: Some(4) }
RefCell { value: Some(5) }
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

[Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) is another topic about storing the value in the same struct, but the answer doesn't show the cases where the value can be moved, or the usage of `RefCell`.

Is there a way to modify that `RefCell` so that I can modify the reference?

Comment: Looks like it'd be better if `cur_num` were just an index for the `nums` array, no?

Comment: Your `nums` property must be `Rc<RefCell<u32>>` and your `cur_num` must be `Option<Rc<RefCell<u32>>>`. Then you can update value by mutable reference at once.

Comment: @Dmitry I see your point, but how would I be able to update that value if nums is an array, while cur_num is an element? 
I am stuck at how to assign curr_num.
Playground:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e1bf479ed3a5bf54979ae7769024689f

Comment: Dmitry's suggestion was to do something more like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3df5190597b4ae96a223b1c2cec40e13).

Comment: @kmdreko thank you! that explains a lot.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake was that your `nums` must be `[Rc<RefCell<u32>>; 8]`. See this RPG: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fbac44d14059f6075f25806fef36b573